# How to see a branch created in master

Tags: git

I create a branch in my master repository (192.168.1.2). 
And in my other computer, I did '$ git pull --rebase ', I see

```
Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), done.
From git+ssh://richard@192.168.1.2/media/LINUXDATA/mozilla-1.9.1
62d004e..b291703  master     -> origin/master
* [new branch]      improv -> origin/improv
```

But when I do a 'git branch' in my local repository, I see only 1 branch and I did '$ git checkout improv '

```
$ git branch                                              
* master
$ git checkout improv                                 
error: pathspec 'improv' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Did you forget to 'git add'?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$ git fetch origin` first. Other than that, your git version might not be as fresh so you should do `$ git checkout --track -b improv origin/improv`

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you have two problems:

- your local working copy isn't up-to-date, and
- locally, you don't have an `improv` branch that tracks the copy on the server (similar to how `master` tracks `origin/master`).

First, you need to run:

```
$ git fetch
```

Which will update your remote refs (locally, a ref to `origin/improv` will appear). Then, run:

```
$ git checkout -b improv --track origin/improv
```

To create a new local branch, `improv`, that tracks the branch on the server, `origin/improv`. (This branch will be up-to-date on your local machine.) Your local `improv` branch will then automatically merge changes from `improv` on the server (and hence, your other machine) when you run `git pull`.

Answer (score 1):

To checkout and create the branch together from master, you need to do this:

```
git checkout origin/master -b improv
```

To list the branches at remote repository, you should use

```
git branch -r
```

or just use

```
git branch -a
```

to list all branches including both remote and local ones.

Comment: If your current branch is already `master`, you can shorten the checkout command to just `git checkout -b improv`.

Answer (score 0):

The new branch, improv, exists on the origin (your master repository) but is not pulled when issuing a `$git pull command` This is by design. On your local machine you probably want to do something like `$git checkout --track origin/improv` to pull the brach and add it to your local track list.